# Visualizing Data via Highcharts and Django-Chartit2 on App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, highcharts

I'm working on a project where I need to get data representations from the database into graphs the users can see. I'm using Django 1.9 and the application is running on the app engine.

I've implemented Django-Chartit as such: 
(Basically same as this tutorial from [Chartit2](https://github.com/grantmcconnaughey/django-chartit2))

view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Result

from chartit import DataPool, Chart

def myresults(request):
    resultatData = DataPool(series=
        [{'options':{
            'source': Result.objects.filter(user=request.user).filter(tot25__gt=250)},
            'terms': [
                'date',
                'tot25']}
        ])


    cht = Chart(
        datasource=resultatData,
        series_options=
        [{'options':{
            'type': 'line',
            'stacking': False,
            'allowPointSelect': True,
            'lineWidth': 5,
            'color': '#f7a35c'},
            'terms':{
                'date':[
                    'tot25']
            }}],
        chart_options = {
            'title': {
                'text': 'Results'},
            'xAxis':{
                'title':{
                    'text': 'Date'}}})



    context = {
        'resultchart': cht,
    }

    return render(request, 'resultat/myResults.html', context)
```

myResults.html

```
{% block CustomIncludes %}
{% load chartit %}
{{ resultchart|load_charts:"container" }}
{% endblock CustomIncludes %}

{% block content %}
<div id='container'> Graph</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

This example works great when I run the server with Django's manage.py runserver

However, with dev_appserver.py or in uploaded to my GAE app, it doesnt display the graph, with no apparant errors.

---

Anybody has any clue what is going on?

Anything to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Also, any suggestions for alternative ways of doing this would be awesome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have found the solution.

The Google App Engine and Django servers seem to handle Static folders differently. The static folder inside the chartit library was not registered, so the chartloader.js was not avaiable.

I just moved the contents of the static folder of chartit into my static folder in the base of the project, and the graphs worked fine. (There are probably better ways to handle this, but it fixed my issue for now.)